# How to add one hundred div's in one .querySelector()? [MINESWEEPER]

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

so I've got 100 blocks, 10x10 (Well, you know, like good old Minesweeper).
Instead of copying and pasting document.querySelector('d1') 100 times, is there any other way to have the same result, but with less lines of Code? I've already tried to add class 'd', but console returns only the first div. Also, I made an array of numbers, and console returns null :/ Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common class and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a list of matches rather than just the first match.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally forgot about querySelectorAll! You are the king!